# How to create a database using JDBC in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

This is what I have tried, starting with [clojure.java.jdbc](https://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc) and a map containing the database connection details:

```
(:require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as j]))

(def mysql-db {:dbtype "mysql", :dbname "changelog_development", :user "root", :password "", :useSSL true, :verifyServerCertificate false}
```

First I tried to use [execute](https://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/execute!) but it cannot use the given connection configuration because the database does not yet exist:

```
(j/execute! mysql-db "CREATE DATABASE changelog_development") ;; MySQLSyntaxErrorException Unknown database 'changelog_development'
```

So I remove that `dbname` key and tried again, however the error says I have a missing parameter:

```
(j/execute! (dissoc mysql-db :dbname) "CREATE DATABASE changelog_development") ;; IllegalArgumentException db-spec {:dbtype "mysql", :user "root", :password "", :useSSL true, :verifyServerCertificate false} is missing a required parameter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clojure.java.jdbc` connection spec has many possible formats. The one with keys for `:dbtype`, `:user` etc requires that you also specify a `:dbname`.

You can also specify your connection spec using a connection URI instead and execute your statement again:

`{:connection-uri "jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password="}`